# Improve or burn the [cs50] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[cs50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cs50) needs to go or be renamed. It can be interpreted in 2 ways:

- The class CS50
- cs50.h

I think we should rename the tag to `cs50.h` to refer to this library, not the class.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not necessary.

The tag info saying

> The CS50 course is a self-study introductory computer science course from Harvard. There is a C library available for use with the course. **This tag should be used for questions which use the cs50.h header or cs50 library along with the C tag.**

in the title and in the body,

> This tag should be used for questions which use the "cs50.h" header or -lcs50 library. Another symptom that it is appropriate is the use of the type string (which is defined with typedef char *string; in the cs50.h header) or functions such as GetChar(), GetDouble(), GetFloat(), GetString(), GetInt() and GetLongLong().

So, it is very clear that it is used for `cs50.h` header file

Comment: But there are also questions about this CS50 course that are related to Python or Javascript exercises, and they are not related to "cs50.h" file. Should they be tagged with [tag:cs50]?